# Exception when trying to bind XAML Data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a simple application about sports news. The problem is that then I try to bind data I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll Additional information: Items
>   collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

And here is the xaml code:

```
<ListView Name="ListBoxWithNews" ItemsSource="{Binding News}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURL}" Width="75" Height="75" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView>
```

I set the data context this way:

```
private void EnglandNews_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewsModelView model = new NewsModelView("http://topsport.ibox.bg/rss_18");
            this.DataContext = model;
        }
```

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Comment: when you first run your application the ListBoxWithNEws is looking for its binding which is News, that's why you got an error.

Comment: you have to change your News property declaration can you please share how you declare it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap that `StackPanel` in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListView Name="ListBoxWithNews" ItemsSource="{Binding News}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURL}" Width="75" Height="75" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Without using the `ItemTemplate.DataTemplate` you end up actually having items in the list from the base markup.

Comment: The data template should be nested under the ListView.ItemTemplate property